# (Android studio) How to get item position from strings.xml if I know the string?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I have a list of strings in strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">XXXXXX MAPS</string>

<string-array name="Field">
    <item>
        AAAAA
    </item>
    <item>
        BBBBB
    </item>
    <item>
        CCCCC
    </item>
    <item>
        DDDDD
    </item>
    <item>
        EEEEE
    </item>
    <item>
        FFFFF
    </item>
    <item>
        GGGGG
    </item>
```

I have put this list in listview.
When I click the listview I will get the String ( for example String clicked = EEEEE)

How can I find the int position from that strings.xml using the information that I know the string that has been clicked? (for example if String EEEEE where clicked I would like to get Int stringclicked = 5)

I want to stress that I want to some way to get it using that list of strings that are in strings.xml. I cannot use something like

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
```

To get int position.

Comment: @Selvin ??? answered so many times where???

Comment: @selvin where? link please

Comment: You couldn't have put it in athe listView without adapter. Use the position you get from adapter. That lead to the position you desire

Comment: i get it know. It was a stupid question. i was just confused because i was using searcview that was filtering the listview and i was getting nowhere.

Comment: Please don't add things like "Answered" to your subject, instead **accept** the answer that was most helpful

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Did not i accept the answer?? Sorry im new. And I put answered because i did not want more answers because this was not a good question and I cant delete it anymore

Comment: That is not how stack overflow works. People answer, you accept an answer, and other people may still answer (you can even decide to accept a newer, better answer instead). You should not delete questions just because you received an answer (your question and its answers are not just for you, but also for the larger community and future visitors), nor should you add meta-info like "answered".

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Did I accept answer??? Yeah I know but the question has been answered manytimes so I do not want to people to use their time writing something again :)

Comment: Yes, you accepted, the point I am trying to make is that you should **only** accept, not add things like "answered".

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I think i accepted the answer many hours ago so I did not get you message. And i thought adding answered would just help. Have a nice day:) bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have list of Strings, what I can see in the question. You can use indexOf method of list for getting position. For example:

```
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("aaa");
    strings.add("bbb");
    strings.add("ccc");
    strings.add("ddd");
    strings.add("eee");
    int position = strings.indexOf("ccc");
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question directly, if you have a string and want to obtain the position in the array in resources:

```
String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Field);
```

Obtain the position in the resources array:

```
 Arrays.asList(stringArray).indexOf(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            try {                                       
                //'position' refers to the 'int position' in the Override method
                Log.e("This is your position", position.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }
        }
    });
```